# Java class duplicate entry

Tags: android

Hello i am getting this error in gradle :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/like/CircleView$1.class

These are my dependencies :

```
 compile project(':library')
    compile project(':likebutton')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.thefinestartist:ytpa:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
```

The error occurs when i added this lib :

```
compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.1'
```

it s making conflict with this one :

```
 compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.3'
```

How can i exclude the com/like/CircleView$1.class from one of the two libs?

and which one to exlude it from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing the `LikeButton` library 2 times.

One using

```
compile project(':likebutton')
```

and one using

```
compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.1'
```

You need to remove one of those statements to be able to build your app

Comment: Thanks a lot i found it five minutes before .
But i appreciate your help
Exact solution.